# Optional route stop others route with same pattern

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

The following is my route to define the optional variable, and I will have a middleware to process the optional variable. I not sure why this make the testing page inaccessible and I believe it is interpreted as the invite code. What's the workaround for this?

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['friend']], function() {

    Route::get('/{invite_code?}', 'IndexController@index')->name('home')->middleware('firsttime'); // 首页

    Route::get('/testing/{invite_code?}', 'IndexController@testing')->name('testing');
});
```

Comment: switching them?

Comment: what do you mean of switching?

Comment: Put the first as the second, and the second as the first. Obviously the second one is more restrictive than the first one. Still it can still fail if the invite_code is "testing"

Comment: it work. what a silly mistake. thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Example i have **these three route**

```
Route::get('/{invite_code?}', function () {
    dd('i am invite code Route');
})->name('invitecode');
Route::get('/myCustomRoute', function () {
    dd( 'i am myCustomRoute');
});
Route::get('/testing/{invite_code?}', function(){
    dd( 'i am testing invite code Route');
})->name('invitecodetest');
```

Now I am serving my app in **8000** Port so `http://localhost:8000/` is my app url

Now when i hit the `myCustomRoute` it Wont actually hit `myCustomRoute` that's because the Router is thing that  `myCustomRoute` as `invite_code`
hit `http://localhost:8000/myCustomRoute` So the result will be **i am invite code Route**

How to fix that

There are two ways

**Way 1 Reorder Routes**

```
Route::get('/myCustomRoute', function () {
    dd( 'i am myCustomRoute');
});
Route::get('/testing/{invite_code?}', function(){
    dd( 'i am testing invite code Route');
})->name('invitecodetest');

Route::get('/{invite_code?}', function () {
    dd('i am invite code Route');
})->name('invitecode');
```

Now try again to hit the route add `{invite_code?}` at the end of web.php

hit `http://localhost:8000/myCustomRoute` result will be **i am myCustomRoute**

Now its working Fine but it has a drawback

now try `http://localhost:8000/myundefinedroutename`

but it will hit the `{invite_code?}` route so its a bug

Way 2 try to add some prefix to route

```
Route::get('/invidecode/{invite_code?}', function ( $invite_code = null) {
    dd( $invite_code, "i am invite code Route");
})->name('invitecode');
Route::get('/myCustomRoute', function () {
    dd( 'i am myCustomRoute');
});
Route::get('/testing/{invite_code?}', function(){
    dd( 'i am testing invite code Route');
})->name('invitecodetest');
```

Now try `http://localhost:8000/invidecode/yourcodegoeshere` Result will be 
**"yourcodegoeshere"
"i am invite code Route"**

and  hit `http://localhost:8000/myCustomRoute` result will be **"i am myCustomRoute"**
and hit `http://localhost:8000/testing/myinvitecode` result will be **"myinvitecode"
"i am testing invite code Route"**